# How to redirect websocket session with an Nginx proxy to an IBM Bluemix webapp?

Tags: nginx, websocket, proxy, ibm-cloud

Here is my ***nginx.conf*** :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream websocket {
        server myapp.onbluemix.net:80;
    }

    server {
       listen 80;
       location / {
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;  
             proxy_pass http://websocket;
           }
    }
}
```

I can ping from nginx proxy server my webapp on bluemix.

Here the **nginx's logs** :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Error
Server: nginx/1.13.3
Content-Type: text/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive  
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
```

I added the webapp's IP address to the nginx's *hosts* file just in case, same error.

Nginx proxy works if i run the webapp on my local machine.

I don't understand that assertion `X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL`

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the internal IBM Proxy is involved, you have to add the host you want to reach in the header (`proxy_set_header host myapp.onbluemix.net;`) like:

```
location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header host myapp.onbluemix.net;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;  
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
}
```